# SQL COLUMN ERROR for JOIN

Tags: sql-server

I have a Dtltable

```
tabid        TickNUM    TickType      Amount

 001-FGF     C2001        Credit      133
 001-FGF     Tk002        Token        23
 001-FGF     Tk003        Token        43
```

Is there anyway, i can pull all the tabid data using single TickNum, coz the tabid is same for all TickNum.

```
Select * from Dtltable
where tickNum = 'C2001'
```

but it displays only particluar TickNum row. I need all rows with similar tabid's as well. Not sure how to write logic.

Comment: I'm unclear as to what you want to do.  Do you want to fetch all the rows with a tabid similar to the row identified by the TickNum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `JOIN`

```
SELECT d1.* 
FROM Dtltable d1
INNER JOIN Dtltable d2 ON d2.tabid = d1.tabid AND d2.TickNUM = 'C2001'
```

Comment: Much preferred in general than a subquery

Answer (score 1):

One method is a subquery:

```
select d.*
from dtltable d
where d.tabid = (select d2.tabid from dtltable d2 where d2.tickNum = 'C2001');
```

If the subquery could return more than one row, use `in` instead of `=`.

Comment: Is there any way that I can add other logic like if Ticktype = Token then amount*-1

Comment: @nmcsr . . . New questions should be asked as questions, not as comments, along with sample data, desired results, and other relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is a bit long, you can achieve this by first selecting distinct data, then by using inner join. Below how I did that.

```
CReate table #temptab
(
tabid nvarchar(20) null,
ticknum nvarchar(10)null,
ticktype varchar(20)null
)

Create table #temptab1
(
tabid nvarchar(20)null,
ticknum nvarchar(10)null,
ticktype varchar(20)null
)

insert into #temptab1(tabid,ticknum)
select distinct tabid , ticknum  from #temptab where ticknum='C2001' // you can pass @param instead of hardcoded value.
```

//below line, where you will get data:

```
select t.tabid,t.ticknum,t.ticktype from #temptab1 t1 inner join #temptab t on t1.tabid= t.tabid
```

Comment: I want to multiply by -1 for particluar TickT type

Comment: What do you mean by multiplying -1 with particular TKT type? Above code is used to get records with single tabid.

Comment: i want to show amount in negative for particular type

Comment: select d.*
from dtltable d
where d.tabid = (select d2.tabid from dtltable d2 where d2.tickNum = 'C2001');  how can i use that here?